# Отбрасывание конца ссылки.

Tags: jquery, javascript

В строке браузера ссылка имеет ввид:
http://site.ru/faq.php?1231231231
или 
http://site.ru/faq.php?456456456456456
и т.д

Для скрипта нужно привети к виду http://site.ru/faq.php

Сам скрипт:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function() {
         $('.navtabs li a').each(function() {
           if ('http://site.ru/faq.php' == window.location.href)
    { 
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});

}); </script>
```

Вот вместо window.location.href нужно наверно что то использовать. 
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var realHref = window.location
realHref = realHref.split('?');
var url = realHref[0];
```

Comment: var realHref = window.location.href
Забыли href.

А так спасибо, помогло.